# Install libjpeg-turbo (>= 2.0.0) and use with meson

Tags: libjpeg, meson-build, libjpeg-turbo

I am looking for a correct way to install `libjpeg-turbo (>= 2.0.0)` and use it with meson. I got installed `libjpeg-turbo-official_2.1.1` deb.

```
jpg_dep = dependency('libjpeg', fallback: ['libjpeg-turbo', 'jpeg_dep'], version: '>= 2.0.0', required: false)
```

Gives me an error:

```
Package libturbojpeg was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libturbojpeg.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
Package 'libturbojpeg', required by 'project', not found
```

I also tried using wrapper: `meson wrap install libjpeg-turbo`

```
libjpeg = subproject('libjpeg-turbo')
jpg_dep = libjpeg.get_variable('dependency_names')
```

But it also gives an error `ERROR: Requested variable "dependency_names" not found.` (dependency_names is a correct name from libjpeg-turbo.wrap)

Previously I successfully used libjpeg-turbo installed with apt-get, but as I need newer version and apt-get for ubuntu is 1.5.2 only, I have to upgrade it in my project somehow.

Comment: Are the library's dev files installed?

Comment: You have the name for the subproject dependency backwards `dependency_names` is the *key* the value is `libjpeg`